# How to snap pattern handles in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have this pattern which I'm trying to adjust to a key box (and to all shapes filled using this pattern):
[image: Screenshot]

There are 3 handles below the box (the 3rd one is way below the screenshot). The x marks the position, the o marks the orientation. The problem is, when I try to set the x handle on the upper-left part of the box, it doesn't snap into place (and I can't find a way to adjust it perfectly using coordinates). Is there a way of snapping it on this corner?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't really understand why you would want the pattern controls to snap to anything. What are you trying to achieve?  But in any case the control handles can snap to guides, so just place some guides.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Billy Kerr, I found the solution: handles snap to guides